# Using Prepared Statement in Complex query

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to use Prepared Statement for processing queries. The problem is I have severals if else statements that changes query based on the user input.

Here is my code

```
                if(  !star_firstName.isEmpty() ||  !star_lastName.isEmpty()  ){
                    baseQuery = "select m.id, title, year, director, banner_url, trailer_url from movies m, stars s, stars_in_movies sim WHERE m.id=sim.movie_id AND s.id=sim.star_id";
                }
                if(!searchtext.isEmpty())
                    baseQuery = baseQuery +  " AND upper(title) like '%" + searchtext.toUpperCase() + "%'" ;
                if(!movie_year.isEmpty())
                    baseQuery = baseQuery +  " AND year=" + movie_year;
                if(!movie_director.isEmpty())
                    baseQuery = baseQuery +  " AND upper(director) like '%" + movie_director.toUpperCase() + "%'";
                if( !star_firstName.isEmpty())
                    baseQuery = baseQuery +  " AND upper(first_name) like '%" + star_firstName.toUpperCase() + "%'" ;
                if( !star_lastName.isEmpty())
                    baseQuery = baseQuery +  " AND upper(last_name) like '%" + star_lastName.toUpperCase() + "%'" ;

                if(!title1.isEmpty() ){
                    baseQuery =  "SELECT m.id, title, year, director, banner_url, trailer_url FROM movies m where m.title like '" + title1 + "%" +  "'";

                }
                if(  !genre.isEmpty()){
                    baseQuery =  "SELECT m.id, title, year, director, banner_url, trailer_url FROM movies m, genres g, genres_in_movies gim where g.id=gim.genre_id and  m.id = gim.movie_id and g.name='" + genre + "'";
                }



                System.out.println(baseQuery);
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(baseQuery);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to put my main question. The code snippet works but I want to optimize the performance by using PreparedStatement.
. My question is how can I achieve the same result using PreparedStatement?

Answer (score 0):

A `PreparedStatement` won't help you in this case.

A `PreparedStatement` only helps performance if the query stays the same, and all that varies are the constants.

The other use of a `PreparedStatement` is to avoid the danger of SQL injection.
If that's what you are after, you could proceed like this (untested):

```java
java.util.Vector<String> params = new Vector();
StringBuffer baseQuery = new StringBuffer("SELECT ...");

...

if (!dweebnoid.isEmpty()) {
    baseQuery.append(" AND upper(dweebnoid) LIKE ?");
    params.add("%" + dweebnoid + "%");
}

...

java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt =
    conn.prepareStatement(baseQuery.toString());
for (i=0; i<params.size();++i)
    pstmt.setString(i+1, params.get(i));
java.sql.ResultSet resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you but it would be great  if you could tell me how to write this in preparedStatement. I  wan to avoid SQL injection too.

Comment: I have added an example (assuming all parameters are strings; adapt the code to your needs).